# Storing little amount of data in android

Tags: java, android

There are 2000 records of data. The only thing I want to do with records is getting values(no removing or editing). Data is not hard-structured. I can treat data as key-value storage. I'm going to init data from file (about 1mb) when app starts and then keep it in array or hashtable. Is that a good idea to store it in memory?

Comment: You can use a light database like SQLite.

Comment: Be careful with storing that in memory, because of you map that structure to classes and store it in map or whatever it will be a way more heavy than 1mb. Consider using sqlite, with cursors you have great advantage - lazy loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is not good idea to have that data in memory, because you will have to keep the data in every android lifecycle step, although you can store the data in key-value i think you should store it in a database and access it throught a content provider.

Content Provider Basics:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Using large amount of data, best practice is **sqlite**

Here is very good SQLite [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

another tuorial http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742